# Trouble centering items within parents in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styling

I’m having trouble aligning two components within another div in React. I’m using relative positioning for the parent div (snippetButtonHolder) and absolute positioning for its children (snippet and button). I want snippet to be centered in the parent and button to be under snippet and to the right, but for some reason when I use these attributes they are positioned relative to the entire page, not to the parent div. Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I should do differently?

```
const styles = {
    module: {
        marginTop: '30px',
        padding: '20px',
    },
    snippet: {
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
        border: 'solid 1px #ccc',
        borderRadius: '4px',
        margin: '0 auto',
        padding: '10px',
        width: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '50%',
    },
    snippetButtonHolder: {
        width: '95%',
        position: 'relative',
    },
    button: {
        float: 'right',
        marginTop: '5px',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '94%',

    },
};

export default class CodeSnippet extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles.module}>
                <div style={styles.snippetButtonHolder}>
                    <div style={styles.snippet}>
                        <div 
                            {'text will go here'}
                        </div>
                        {this.state.showButton ?
                            <button
                                style={styles.button}>
                                Press me
                            </button>
                        : null}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
const styles = {
    module: {
        marginTop: '30px',
        padding: '20px',
    },
    snippet: {
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
        border: 'solid 1px #ccc',
        borderRadius: '4px',
        display: 'inline-block',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        padding: '10px',
    },
    snippetButtonHolder: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        width: '95%',
    },
    button: {
        float: 'right',
        marginTop: '5px',
    },
};
```